No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for EC key
When connecting to an internal device with a JDK17 with TLS v1.2, the handshake fails with this error:
No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for EC key

My key uses the EC "secp256r1", and the negociated signature algorithm is "ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384".
The CertificateVerity stage fails because the "ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384" can't be used with the named group "secp256r1". I see in the log:
Ignore the signature algorithm (ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384), 
unsupported EC parameter spec: secp256r1

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SignatureScheme.java#L503
When I try to connect to this device with openssl and the same certificate/pkey, It works without any issue.
Is it something "not implemented yet" into the jdk, or what I am doing wrong here ?
Due to the nature of this device, I can't use others algorithms for the key or the signature.

This looks like a bug. Sigalgs 0x0503 in TLSv1.3 is ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 but in TLSv1.2 it is only ecdsa+sha384 i.e. the curve is constrained in 1.3 but not in 1.2, so in 1.2 it is legal to use this sigalg with your secp256r1-aka-P256 key/cert. It is inefficient securitywise and not recommended, but it is legal. Until/unless you can get this fixed in SunJSSE, you could use BouncyCastle (BCJSSE works), or you could revert to a Java version below 8u291 (losing all newer features and fixes). Or you could do the TLS externally with something like stunnel or socat (both using OpenSSL).

Thanks for your comments. I will try with BCSSE instead, and fill an issue on the openjdk jira.
